# Python: calculating checksum of a file for a weird protocol

Tags: python

I'm having troubles calculating something like a checksum of a file for a weird protocol that I'm trying to port to python.

The checksum is a 4 byte unsigned integer that is the result of adding all the 4-bytes unsigned integers of a file. For example, suppose the following file (note that a real one is about 16MB):

```
ff fe fd fc fb fa f9 f8  f7 f6 f5 f4 f3 f2 f1 f0
ef ee ed ec eb ea e9 e8  e7 e6
```

With my implementation (see below), the computation is as this:

```
0xfffefdfc + 0xfbfaf9f8 + 0xf7f6f5f4 + 0xf3f2f1f0 + 0xefeeedec + 0xebeae9e8 + 0xe7e60000 = 0x6aba3b7ac
```

But, it should be `0xaba3b7ac`

I've tried to do something like this:

```
import mmap
import struct

# Prepare file
file = open("file.bin", 'rb')
map = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

# Calculate checksum
checksum = 0
while (map.tell() < map.size()):
    checksum += struct.unpack('>I', map.read(4))[0]

print "checksum: ", checksum

# Close file.
map.close()
file.close()
```

But I see two problems.

1. First of all, the output number is too big. I need a 4 byte number.
   With the previous code, the output for a typical test file is something like
   `0x165c0458b224ae` but it should be something like `0xcaac5458` (a 4-byte unsigned
   integer).
2. My method is slow. The original code (which is written in C) does
   the calculation much faster.

I'm really stuck with this so any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

---

**Update:**

The first problem was solved by Serge Ballesta. The solution is to add the following line before printing the checksum:

```
checksum &= 0xffffffff
```

But the computation is still slow. I would like to have a fast solution but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This _is_ a checksum, but it's not a CRC, so it's not a good idea to use that term in your code.

Comment: Is the file too large to fit in memory? Why are you using mmap instead of the `array` module or better `numpy` if it's availiable?

Comment: You should open the file in read-binary 'rb'.

Comment: Can't you write a Python binding for the C code instead ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202306/python-bindings-how-does-it-work

Comment: The input file is big (16 MB). That is the reason about using mmap. Also, I cannot use the original C code because it was compiled in a windows maching and this code is for a linux machine.

Comment: Do you know what the correct number should be and what your code output for it? If you have concrete examples, please post them as well.

Comment: The number is too large because python automatically converts ints to longs as needed and will grow as large as the memory on the system allows. Your checksum value just keeps growing instead of wrapping.  You'll need to write a function to check when checksum is > 4294967295 and manually wrap the value when it is.

Comment: You don't need to keep checking `map.tell() < map.size()`, because your just want to keep reading the file till the end. Your loop should quit when you've reached the end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `array` module and load all the four bytes into memory, sum those, then force back to a 4 byte (as Serge has already mentioned).

```
import os
from array import array

#with open('data.bin', 'wb') as fout:
#   fout.write(os.urandom(16800000))

with open('data.bin', 'rb') as fin:
    arr = array('L')
    arr.fromfile(fin, 16800000 / 4)
    arr.byteswap()
    checksum = sum(arr) & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Takes less than a second on my laptop... not sure how much faster you want it to go...

Comment: This version is indeed much faster but I think (maybe I'm wrong) that the numbers are read in little-endian so the final result is wrong.

Comment: Perfect! A fast and accurate solution, just what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problems, but not those you describe.

Passing from an arbitrary long number to a 4 byte integer is as simple as `n4b = n & 0x0FFFFFFFF`

I do not understand why *computing* C source code writen for a Windows machine could not be compiled on a Unix one.

That being said, `6293623225328814 & 0xFFFFFFFF` gives `1488069806` or `0x58b224ae` in hexa, which is not your expected result. I suppose you have and endianness problem. You should first compute it in little endian and big endian to know which to choose.

```
# Calculate checksum
checksum_be = 0
checksum_le = 0
while (map.tell() < map.size()):
    checksum_be += struct.unpack('>I', map.read(4))[0]
    checksum_le += struct.unpack('<I', map.read(4))[0]
checksum_be &= 0x0FFFFFFFF
checksum_le &= 0x0FFFFFFFF

print "checksums: ", checksum_be, checksum_le
```

Comment: First of all, I've to clarify that I don't have the source code (I only have the executable file). Basically, I'm doing reverse engineering.

All calculations are done in big endian. Using the bitwise operation, the number is calculated correctly but the operation is still slow.

Is there any way to speed up the computation?

Comment: @sentencia : apart from rewriting the whole thing in C (which is effectively much faster), I have no better idea.