# How do the different parts of a program written in different programming languages interact with each other?

Tags: computer-science

For example, NodeJS has the "http" module. With this module you can write the following code:

```
var server = new http.Server(); 
server.listen(3000);
```

But JavaScript itself has no functionality to interact with the hardware, so from what I understand the JavaScript code communicates with the libuv library written in C. What is the principle of this interaction?
Also, I have come across some phrases like this: "...this is a Python library written in C for...", but I don't understand how such projects can work at all.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10202306/217324

Comment: The "principle" is that a language X implementor provides a way to be able to call code written in language Y -- i.e., there is a perceived need for that to work, so someone makes it work.   Generally, Y is going to be a compiled language, so what you're really calling is just some machine code; the implementor of X provides interface mechanisms.  Often, "Y" is actually C, since there's a lot of useful C libraries out there.